# PHP contact form with Jquery validation not working

Tags: php, jquery, contact-form

Problem is, whatever I tried did not work. Tried my own script, tried everything, then found some on google and tried them but no, don't know what's missing but, it doesn't work.
The closest so far, I had empty emails. This is the latest version. Can anyone tell me what's missing ?

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                        <p id="returnmessage"></p>
                        <form action="sendEmail.php" id="contact_form" method="post">
                            <h2 style="font-size:14px;line-height:18px;font-weight:600;padding-bottom:0;">Bize Yazın</h2>
                            <ul class="contactform">
                                <li>
                                    <div id="name_error" class="error" style="color:#aa3939; font-size:8px; line-height:8px;"> <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Lütfen adınızı giriniz.</div>
                                    <span class="contact-input-icon" style="text-align:left"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                    <div class="input-field">
                                        <input type="text" style="border:1px solid rgba(220,220,220,0.5)" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="" class="required requiredField" placeholder="Ad Soyad"/>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <div id="email_error" class="error" style="color:#aa3939; font-size:8px; line-height:8px;"> <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Lütfen eposta adresinizi giriniz.</div>
                                    <span class="contact-input-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                                    <div class="input-field">
                                        <input type="email" style="border:1px solid rgba(220,220,220,0.5)" name="contactEmail" id="contactEmail" value="" class="required requiredField email" placeholder="Eposta"/>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                        <input type="text" style="border:1px solid rgba(220,220,220,0.5)" name="contactSubject" id="contactSubject" value="" class="hidden" placeholder=""/>
                                </li>
                                <li class="textarea">
                                    <div id="message_error" class="error" style="color:#aa3939; font-size:8px; line-height:8px;"> <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i> Lütfen mesajınızı giriniz.</div>
                                    <span class="contact-input-icon"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
                                    <div class="input-field">
                                        <textarea name="contactMessage" style="border:1px solid rgba(220,220,220,0.5)" id="contactMessage" rows="6" cols="20" class="required requiredField" placeholder="Mesajınız"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="mail_success" class="success" style="color:#00CC00"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> İlginiz için teşekkürler. En kısa sürede sizinle irtibata geçeceğiz.</div>
                                    <div id="mail_fail" class="error" style="color:#aa3939"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Üzgünüz, mesajınız iletilemedi. Daha sonra lütfen tekrar deneyin.</div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="buttons">
                                    <div id="cf_submit_p">
                                    <input type="hidden" style="border:1px solid rgba(220,220,220,0.5)" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                                    <button type="submit" style="border:1px solid #3f97cf" class="button" id="send_message"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" style="font-size:20px;color:#3f97cf"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </form>
                    </div> <!--end container-fluid-->
                </div><!-- #contact-canvas -->
```

JS validation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#send_message').on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var error = false;
            var name = $('#contactName').val();
            var email = $('#contactEmail').val();
            var subject = $('#contactSubject').val();
            var message = $('#contactMessage').val();
            if(name.length == 0){
                var error = true;
                $('#name_error').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('#name_error').fadeOut(500);
            }
            if(email.length == 0 || email.indexOf('@') == '-1'){
                error = true;
                $('#email_error').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('#email_error').fadeOut(500);
            }
            if(message.length == 0){
                error = true;
                $('#message_error').fadeIn(500);
            } else {
                $('#message_error').fadeOut(500);
            } if(error == false){
                $('#cf_submit_p').attr({'disabled' : 'true', 'value' : 'Gönderiliyor...' });
                $.post("send_email.php", $("#contact_form").serialize(),function(result){
                    if(result == 'sent'){
                        $('#cf_submit_p').remove();
                        $('#mail_success').fadeIn(500);
                    } else {
                        $('#mail_fail').fadeIn(500);
                        $('#cf_submit_p').removeAttr('disabled').attr('value', 'Gönder');
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And PHP

```
<?php



//Değiştir. Site admini eposta adresi. 

$akaEmail = 'kreaft@outlook.com';





if($_POST) {



   $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));

   $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));

   $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));

   $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));



   // İsim doğrulama

    if (strlen($name) < 2) {

        $error['name'] = "Lütfen adınızı girin.";

    }

    // Email doğrulama

    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {

        $error['email'] = "Lütfen geçerli bir eposta adresi girin.";

    }

    // Mesaj doğrulama

    if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {

        $error['message'] = "Lütfen mesajınızı girin. (Min. 15 karakter)";

    }

   // Konu

    if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Site İletişim Formu"; }





   // Mesajı oluşturuyoruz

   $message .= "Gönd.: " . $name . "<br />";

   $message .= "Eposta: " . $email . "<br />";

   $message .= "Mesaj: <br />";

   $message .= $contact_message;

   $message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> Bu eposta site iletişim formu üzerinden gönderilmiştir. <br />";



   // Başlıkları oluşturuyoruz

   $from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";



   // Başlıklar

    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";

    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";

    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";





   if (!$error) {



      ini_set("sendmail_from", $akaEmail); // windows server için

      $mail = mail($akaEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);



        if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }

      else { echo "Bir hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyin."; }



    } # hiç bir doğrulama hatası çıkmazsa bitir, çıkarsa hataları listeliyoruz.



    else {



        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;

        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;

        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;



        echo $response;



    } # bir doğrulama hatası olmuşsa burada bitir.



}



?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: 'Notice: Undefined variable: message in /Users/kobigo/Sites/yedikitamuhendislik.com/sendEmail.php on line 61' this is the last error, which I noticed right now. @JayBlanchard

Comment: Have you explored why the variable is undefined?

Comment: Narrow down your code to where the problem is. When there are multiple problems, ask mutliple questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice: Undefined variable: message in /Users/kobigo/Sites/yedikitamuhendislik.com/sendEmail.php on line 61

Look at what appears to be line 61:

```
$message .= "Gönd.: " . $name . "<br />";
```

You're trying to append to `$message`, but you never defined it in the first place.  You can append to it *after* it's been defined, but on this first line you need to simply define it and assign to it:

```
$message = "Gönd.: " . $name . "<br />";
```

The remaining similar lines can append to it.

---

You're also attaching to the wrong event in your JavaScript code:

```
$('#send_message').on('submit',function(e){
```

`#send_message` is a button, not a form.  It doesn't have a `submit` event.  Attach to the form instead:

```
$('#contact_form').on('submit',function(e){
```

Comment: Thanks David, that was helpful. Missed that dot there. But now it sends me to another page where it gives the errors, I want it to run Jquery validation first, then post .. Any idea ?

Comment: @vincodisouza: Define "gives the errors".  Understand that I can't see your screen from here.  Stack Overflow is a poor substitute for a debugger, can you specify where exactly the behavior of the code is deviating from what you expect?

Comment: the error messages, such as "invalid email" etc.. I wanted it to be shown in the same page, tho it redirects me to another page.. I think jquery validations not working. How can I run query validations before php post ?

Comment: @vincodisouza: I've updated the answer.  You were attaching to the wrong event in your JavaScript code.  This would be a great opportunity to take a look at your browser's debugging tools to help you step through the code and see runtime values.  Debugging is an *invaluable* process when writing code.

Comment: thanks for that correction. I was toggling between button-click form-submit .. forgot it.. Thanks.. Well now I see my validation error messages, but the form doesn't react. No error, or success message, and no mails was sent. Any idea ?

Comment: @vincodisouza: I can't stress this enough... Stack Overflow is *not* a substitute for debugging.  I can't see your screen or step through your code for you.  I'm happy to help by answering questions (such as the two I've answered so far), but "it doesn't work" isn't a valid problem description and I can't tinker with your code on your computer and figure it out for you.  Use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks for all you've done so far @David . I understand.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to append to `$message` variable on line 61 without initializing it first. Fix line 61 by removing append sign `.`

```
 $message = "Gönd.: " . $name . "<br />";
```

Or initializing variable first like:

```
 $message = "";
```